# RewriteRule - two parameters but last parameter is optional

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

I cannot rewrite to include two parameters but the last parameter is optional, so for example:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/friends/jamie - (the forward slash should be optional too). Which should be the same as this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/friends.php?name=jamie
```

When including a second parameter

> http://www.mywebsite.com/friends/jamie/30  - Should be the same as this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/friends.php?name=jamie&page=30
```

This rule does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^friends/(.*)/(.*)$ friends.php?name=$1&page=$2
```

Because I get this: `The requested URL /friends/jamie was not found on this server.` but works if I include a page number for the second parameter, so basically the second parameter should be optional.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try using this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^friends/([^/]*)/?(.*)$ friends.php?name=$1&page=$2
```

Hope that helps