# seo url rewrite rule - make last parameter optional

Tags: .htaccess, seo

This works but always expects the last parameter - I need 'page' to be optional for pagination purposes.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /catalogue.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809602/rewriterule-two-parameters-but-last-parameter-is-optional) from a previous stack post but it gives me a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /catalogue.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /catalogue.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

If it is Ok for you with empty page, and as you use the same page `catalogue.php` in both cases, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)$ /catalogue.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```